# How to delete space in Python?

Tags: python

I have a question about How to delete a space in my guessing game.

Here is my source code:

```
import random
print ("I’m thinking of an integer, you have three guesses.")

def tovi_is_awesome():

    random_integer = random.randint (1, 10)
    chances = 3



    for i in [1,2,3]:
        print ("Guess", i, ": ", end=" ")
        guess = eval(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 10:  "))

        if guess < random_integer:
            print ("Your guess is too small.")

        elif guess > random_integer:
            print ("Your guess is too big.")

        else:
            print ("You got it!")
            break


    if guess != random_integer:
        print ("Too bad.  The number is:  ", random_integer)

tovi_is_awesome ()
```

When I run it, I got this:
I’m thinking of an integer, you have three guesses.
Guess 1 :  Please enter an integer between 1 and 10:

How can I delete that space after "Guess 1"?
Or are there any better ways to avoid that space?

Thank you!
This is my first question in SOF lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print ("Guess", i, ": ", end=" ")
```

You could write it like;

```
print ("Guess {}: ".format(i), end=" ")
```

So you can avoid from that space. You could check [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/new-str-format.html) one for examples.

Here is a simple guess game, check it carefully please. It may improve your game. You dont' have to use `eval()`.

```
random_integer = random.randint (1, 10)
chances = 3
gs=1
while 0<chances:
    print ("Guess {}".format(gs))
    guess = int(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 10:  "))

    if guess<random_integer:
        print ("Your guess is too small.")
        chances -= 1 #lost 1 chance
        gs += 1 #increase guess number

    elif guess > random_integer:
        print ("Your guess is too big.")
        chances -= 1
        gs +=1

    else:
        print ("You got it!")
        break
```

It's really simple, just showing you some basic logic. You may consider in the future catching errors with `try/except` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`print ("Guess %d:" % (i) )`

Writing this way will delete the space.